# llvm JIT addGlobalMapping, can not add a class member function, which is a template function

Tags: c++, templates, llvm

I used LLVM to code-gen, but I encounter a problem.

I have a class as below:

```
class AAA {
  public:
    template<typename Type>
    void func(Type str) {
      std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }

    void func2() {
      std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And I have a `llvm::ExecutionEngine* mJit`;

Now I want to use `addGlobalMapping` to add the `AAA::func` and `AAA::func2` to the llvm's global mapping.

```
// success
mJit->addGlobalMapping(fn_func2, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&AAA::func2));

// failed
// Because the `AAA::func` is an template function
mJit->addGlobalMapping(fn_func, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&AAA::func));
```

And then I tried one method as follow:

```
template<class Class, typename K>
using TemplateFunc = void (Class::*) (K);

TemplateFunc<AAA, int> myFunc = &AAA::func;
mJit->addGlobalMapping(fn_func, reinterpret_cast<void*>(myFunc));
```

But it came an error when link:

> llvm::Finalize(): error: undefined reference to "void
>   AAA::func(int)". collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So how to add a c++ template function to the llvm JIT global mapping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the linker error because you function `AAA::func<int>()` is never instantiated. You can solve this by explicitly instantiating the function for `int`:

```
template void AAA::func<>(int);
```

That forces the compiler to actually generate code.